# MacBook Pro Charging Issues

Tags: battery, charging, macos

Last night I plugged in my MacBook Pro, and I noticed the light on the charger was a very faint green, hardly visible in bright light.

Today I opened my Mac and noticed it stated 'batteries not available.' Reading forum posts online I decided to reset the SMC, so I turned it off, pressed the required key combination for the reset and then tried to turn it on. The Mac won't power on. I've tried multiple chargers.

Comment: Is the macbook still under warranty? And is there a store in your local neighbourhood, they can check for you if the battery died.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, I have an Apple store within reasonable distance. If the battery 'died,' I presume it will have to be sent to Apple for a replacement?

Comment: Are you still under warranty or do you have Apple Care? And what kind of Macbook do you have? You can get a cheaper replacement online, but please be aware of real fake stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem isn't the charger - try wiping down the magsafe contacts on your Mac with a medical alcohol pad, if they get too dirty it won't charge. I had a similar issue (green light while discharging) and cleaning the contacts improved the connection for a few days till I could replace the charger.